# Changing data to matrix

Tags: r, xgboost

I don't understand the `[,-1]` indexing part here. `dat` refers to the data What does this accomplish?

[Original source](https://rpubs.com/mharris/multiclass_xgboost)

Sample code:

```
data_variables <- as.matrix(dat[,-1])
```

Comment: It excludes the first column

Comment: See section 2.7 of https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html

Answer (score 1):

Some reference notes on indexing values from a matrix:
If x is your datafile...

```
x[i, j]       #pulls the specific value at row i, column j
x[i, ]        #pulls the values from row i
x[ , j]       #pulls the values from column j
x[ , c(1, 3)] #pulls values from specifically columns 1 and 3
x["name", ]   #pulls the values from the row titled "name"
x[-2, ]       #pulls values from all rows EXCEPT column 2
x[ , -(3:4)]  #pulls all column values EXCEPT columns 3 & 4
```

**NOTE**: using the minus sign only works with row or column *numbers*.  You can't use the minus sign with the "name" identifier.  This will generate an error code.